# Adding new coordinates to a list not working for me

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to get this code to work and with this code I get this error:

```
  File "E:\Snacks.py", line 93, in runGame
    obsCoords.insert(0, newobs)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

That is because I've set a location after the list:

```
obsCoords = []
obscoords = getRandomLocation()

if (event.key == K_q) and len(wormCoords) >= 4:
    del wormCoords[-1]  
    obsCoords['x'] = wormBody['x']
    obsCoords['y'] = wormBody['y']
    newobs = {'x': obsCoords['x'], 'y': obsCoords['y']}
    obsCoords.insert(0, newobs)

if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == obsCoords['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == obsCoords['y']:
            return
```

so I remove it:

```
obsCoords = []

if (event.key == K_q) and len(wormCoords) >= 4:
    del wormCoords[-1]  
    obsCoords['x'] = wormBody['x']
    obsCoords['y'] = wormBody['y']
    newobs = {'x': obsCoords['x'], 'y': obsCoords['y']}
    obsCoords.insert(0, newobs)

if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == obsCoords['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == obsCoords['y']:
            return
```

and end up with this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

All I would like to do is add new locations to the list. Can any one help me please?

Comment: use dictionary instead of list, see this https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Your code is not clear. What are you trying to do? Also it seems like your code is not the same as the code that generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

in your first code, you have two mistakes:

```
obsCoords = []
obscoords = getRandomLocation()
```

the first one is that you're actually declaring two different variables that look alike. Though I think it's a typo… which leads me to the second mistake:

```
obsCoords = []
obsCoords = getRandomLocation()
```

here you're creating a list `obsCoords` that you're overwriting with `getRandomLocation()`'s result, whatever it is, which may not be what you want.

Then in your second code, you're doing:

```
obsCoords = []
…
newobs = {'x': obsCoords['x'], 'y': obsCoords['y']}
obsCoords.insert(0, newobs)
…
obsCoords['x']
```

that code has no meaning at all!

You're creating a list `obsCoords`, then you create `newobs` by accessing `obsCoords` like a dictionary to get `x` and `y`. And then you want to insert that in `obsCoords` like it is a list, to finally try to get the `x` value from `obsCoords` like a dict:

```
obsCoords = []               #     obsCoords -> []
obsCoords['x']               #     obsCoords is an empty list.
obsCoords['y']               #     for this to work it should be : {'x': …, 'y': …}
                             #     suppose it did not fail, here's what's next:
obsCoords.insert(0, newobs)  #     obsCoords -> [{'x': …, 'y': …}]
obsCoords['x']               #     again you're accessing like a dict!
```

What do you want? `obsCoords` being a list or a dict?!

Comment: i'm trying to put an object onto the screen when the letter q is pressed behind where the snake is, I will need to create a list of coordinates so that they will stay in the place these will then become obsticals to avoid so i'm not sure I know what I want and i'm not overly confident in what i'm doing as you can tell!

    def drawObs(obsCoords):
        x = obsCoords['x'] * CELLSIZE
        y = obsCoords['y'] * CELLSIZE
        ObsRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, ORANGE, ObsRect)

Comment: well, please do not ask another question as a comment to an answer for another question you asked. I do understand it's not easy to get started, but you should get the basics first. You should get through a python tutorial to understand the different types first, and how they can help you do what you want to do.